# Updating imageview declared in parent class(which includes Navigation view) from derived class in android

Tags: android, android-studio, uiimageview

**Scenario:**
Base class which includes Navigation drawer layout having header section as in usual apps. Header includes an imageview and textview. There's another activity lets say Profile **which is extending from Base class** in my case and **I don't want to change this parent/child behaviour at this point.**

**Problem:**
Profile activity has api call which updates the profile image on server. On getting success in response, I just want to update the navigation drawer `ImageView` regardless of user goes back to other activity or remains at Profile activity.

**What I have tried so far are:**

Declare `ImageView` in Base Activity as static and try to use Picasso to update image in Profile activity api response.

Declare `ImageView` in Base Activity as static and tried `imageview.setBitmap()` method.

Tried to use instance of Base class in Volley success method and use method of base class where I am trying to update `ImageView`.

Tried to use `runOnUiThread()` in api success response but of no success.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785239/pick-image-from-gallery-and-load-it-into-the-imageview-of-the-particular-activit?rq=1) doesn't make sense in my case as the user might not land on base activity while pressing back button. Below is the piece of code in Profile Activity where I am trying to update image in Base Activity

```
   private void uploadImage() {
   
    if (bm == null) {
        uploadProfile();
    }
    else {
        String REGISTER_URL = new SharedPreferenceManager(getApplicationContext()).getKeyFromSharedPrefFile("MySharedPrefs", "globalURL") + "users/mobileupload";
        
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        navBarImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // where navBarImage is declared in BaseActivity Layout Navigation drawer in header layout
                     }
                },
                ....

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Api call is working fine , image is uploading and updating smoothly if I logout and login again.
Now my question is whether there is a way to be able to update the view of parent class instantly ... and if yes, can you provide some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the `SecondActivity` sets the information including adding an Image. So the goal of the task is to automatically update the `FirstActivity's` Drawer's `ImageView`. We cannot just call the view in the `SecondActivity` because the activity should work independently (which means -- they must not know each other).

I believe it is a great usecase for `onActivityResult()` since we want to pass back a result from the `SecondActivity`. The information we need to pass is a `Uri`-- the uri represents the Image location in the device.

`SecondActivity`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();

            // We will pass the value at the previous activity using this code
            Intent responseValue = new Intent();
            responseValue.putExtra(PROFILE_URI_KEY, filePath);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, responseValue);
     }
}
```

The `SecondActivity` recieves a `Uri` from the `CameraActivity`, that `Uri` must also be pass back to the prev. Activity so that it can perform the invalidation of Drawer'a Image.

`MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e(TAG, "We receive someting " + requestCode + " " + (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK));
    if (requestCode == RESUL_KEY_FOR_EDIT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = (Uri) data.getParcelableExtra(EditProfile.PROFILE_URI_KEY);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(uri)
                .fit().
                centerCrop()
                .noFade()
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(navBarImage);
    }
}
```

In our `MainActivity` we are using Picasso for image loading due to improvements in performance.

Comment: Let me try onActivityResult method ... I guess this approach should work...

Comment: You were right, startActivityResult becomes the only way out ... Tried with interface too but didn't work for me ...

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

For this, what you can do is:
First, create an interface and implement in the "**Base Activity**". Then pass instance of this interface to the **Derived Activity** and once you get the response from the server, call this interface method to send the updated image to **BaseActivity**.

In the **BaseActivity** where you have overridden the interface method, update the image using **Picasso**.
Hope it helps.